# Prove that the only matrix with canonical form $\quad\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$ is B itself

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am trying to show that the only matrix $B$ such that $PBP^{-1} = \quad\begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} $  is precisely itself.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is a so-called *scalar matrix* because we can write it as $\lambda I$; a scalar times the identity matrix.

Now, the center of a general linear group consists entirely of scalar matrices like $\lambda I$; we have $M (\lambda I)  = (\lambda I) M$ for all matrices $M$ (and any scalar $\lambda$, really).

So, conjugating $\lambda I$ by *any* other matrix is just going to give you back $\lambda I$.